# Postgresql выдает ошибку проверку подлинности(по паролю)

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, postgresql, ssh

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - пытаюсь подключиться из своей программы к удаленной бд на сервере, через  инструменты intellij idea  подключаюсь спокойно, но сама программа постоянно выдает ошибку провала подлинности по пароли, хотя логин и пароль верный 100%. Пробрасывал порты по ssh-результата не дало. Третий день пытаюсь решить проблему.
Код подключения к бд

```
public class DataBaseManager {
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
private static final String USER = "s285384";
private static final String PASS = "password";
private static Connection connection = null;
private static Statement statement = null;
private static boolean connected;

static {
    DataBaseManager.connect();
}

public static boolean connect() {
    connection = null;
    statement=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("GOOD!");
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Успешное подключение к базе данных");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            connected = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver не найден. Подключите библиотеку PostgreSQL!");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }
    connected = false;
    return false;
}
```

Сама ошибка

```
04:03:49,930 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) ВАЖНО: пользователь "s285384" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю) (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be windows-1251, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

Проброс портов

```
ssh -L 14840:pg:5432 -p 2222 s285384@se.ifmo.ru
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде указано: DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", то есть, он подключается к localhost к порту 5432, но в правилах проброса портов указано: 14840:pg:5432, то есть, порт 5432 сервера pg отображается на локальный порт 14840. Если ты хочешь отобразить порт сервера PostgreSQL на локальный порт 14840, то надо из приложения к нему и подключаться. И ещё имеет смысл проверить имя базы данных, к которой ты подключаешься.

Comment: Спасибо!Помогло